# Bootstrap slideshow in modal pluign

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, cakephp-2.3

I am working in CakePHP 2.3.6. Here I am using Bootstrap's modal plugin. There are contents in the modal, which are coming from another page, using ajax. So, when I click on a link, the modal window appears with that content, from that page, loaded by ajax.

Now, what I want is, when the modal window appears, there will be a slider/gallery/slideshow, to navigate through all other contents. I mean, I want that my users will click on a link, modal window will appear with the content, the user will see the content, then there will be a navigator(like `Carousel plugin`), to navigate through other contents, if the user clicks on "prev/next", "prev/next" content will come from that page, using ajax.

I mean, I want a combination of `Bootstrap's Modal Plugin & Carousel Plugin`, `Carousel Plugin` in `Modal Plugin`, where the contents will come from another page, using ajax.

My modal plugin is :
.
.
.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Name',array('controller'=>'controllers','action'=>'action',$id),array('data-toggle'=>'modal','data-target'=>'.modal'));?>
```

.
.

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="customLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, here, content(s) are coming from `action` action and page, using Ajax. But, I don't find any way to add the `Carousel Plugin(or like)` here. I thought `Carousel Plugin` supports `Ajax content loading`, but I didn't find that.

So, what should I do here ? Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone doesn't have any idea about this ?